# Solving Power Law Distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, power-law

I have data that closely resembles a [`power law`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) distribution. Using Python, I want to approximate the data by solving two equations in the form:

[image]

`y` is the y axis data. In Python it would be `data[i]`. x would be `i + 1`. It follows that we get two equations with two unknown variables at the first data index and at a "random" 2nd one somewhere else in the data:

[image]
[image]

The problem comes down to solving just

[image]

due to mathematical simplification. I don't know how to solve an equation like this using libraries like [`numpy.linalg.solve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html). How do I find the value of `a` using Python?

Comment: You don't need an equation solver... `a = (1/2)* math.log10 ( data[99]/data[0] )`

Comment: Yeah, it appears to work with `a = math.log(data[99] / data[0], 100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it.

```
import math

def get_power_law_variables(data):
    c = data[0]
    middle_index = len(data) / 2
    division = float(data[middle_index]) / c
    logarithm_base = middle_index + 1
    a = math.log(division, logarithm_base)
    return c, a

# Example usage
data = range(50, 150)
c, a = get_power_law_variables(data)
print c, a
```

Comment: Can you explain that why are you using middle_index as the log base?